# Lightweight Jenkins alternative?

Tags: performance, jenkins, java, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi as home developement server. I need to run a build server on it.

Jenkins is horribly slow, takes 10-15 seconds to just load the start page and when I tried to access the admin page I had to stop the Jenkins server after running for 15 minutes on 100% cpu load.

This is unacceptable.

What's considered the best alternative to Jenkins when I just use ant + git to build and want to archivate builds for a smaller number of projects?

Are there any possibilities to speed up my current Jenkins installation? I'm currently using Oracle Java 8 JDK for ARM and tried Jenkins v1.447.2 (the version I get with "apt-get install jekins" with default Rasbian package sources) as well as v1.502 (the latest, which is way faster but still unbearable).

Comment: This raises the obvious question: why would you want to run a continuous-integration system on such a platform?

Comment: It comes in handier than running it on my desktop pc because it can be be online 24h without consuming much energy and it's cheaper than any v-server.

Comment: You need more memory for a Java based CI engine...

Comment: But it's also massively underpowered for this task (consider the network I/O, disk I/O, CPU and memory requirements of doing source-control checkouts and compilation).

Comment: That's why I'am asking for alternatives. Regarding memory there is no problem as max 60% are used, I/O is no matter as the projects aren't huge and it hosts the gits aswell.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth is right - this is unlikely to be viable for a CI server no matter how light your CI tool is.

Comment: The build process doesn't has to be fast, I just want the web interface to respond in a decent time.

Comment: Also, the process may have too little memory if only 60% is used, so all the CPU goes to insane amounts of garbage collection.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Jenkins currently uses about 111MB of -Xmx256M

Comment: Which you determine how?

Comment: Also note that if you overspend physical RAM your pi will swap.  This also degrades performance immensely.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen According to htop the jenkins process uses 22.9% of the memory, total memory usage is 257/485 mb.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, [here's a list](https://github.com/ligurio/awesome-ci) of CI/CD solutions